# Rigorizing a heuristic argument due to Stanley

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, contest-math

A question on the 2006 Putnam exam asks for the value of the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n}^{k+1}}{n^{k}},$$
where $k \ge 2$ is a fixed integer, $a_{0}$ is a fixed positive real number, and $a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n}^{-1/k}$ for $n > 0$.

(SPOILER ALERT)

The solutions posted at Kiran Kedlaya's [Putnam 
Archive](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/) mention a 
heuristic argument due to Richard Stanley for analyzing the 
asymptotics of $a_{n}$: Simply convert the difference equation
$$a_{n+1} - a_{n} = a_{n}^{-1/k}$$
to the differential equation
$$y' = y^{-1/k},$$
and look at the asymptotics of $y$. This works beautifully.

My question is: What is the rigorous version of this heuristic argument? Is there a standard theorem or technique being used here? If so, what are the precise conditions required to make the argument work?

Comment: The $a_n$ can be seen as numerical approximations of $y$ using the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) with step size $1$. The question now becomes a type of "stability question".